# Expected outcome negative for all players?

Tags: probability

I'm trying to calculate the expected outcome of a dice game.  Without going into the rules and probabilities as it's quite complicated, I was wondering if you could tell me if my results make any sense.  Basically, I am trying to figure out the impact of the number of players to expected payoff.  The buy in is the same for everyone.

Turns out, if 2 people play, your expected outcome is 0.  Ok, makes sense.
If 3 people play, your expected outcome becomes negative.
If 4 people play, your expected outcome becomes an even greater negative.
I've calculated out to 8 people and your expected outcome becomes more and more negative as the number of players increase.

Which brings me to my question.  If my expected outcome is negative, then shouldn't someone's expected outcome be positive?  Intuitively, how does it make sense that every individual's expected outcome is negative?  Who wins at this game?  I mean money can't just disappear.  Expected outcomes should be additive right, so how does this make sense?

Comment: If the game is exactly the same from everyone's point of view then all the expectations should be the same.  But note that this means **exactly** the same - if for example it is determined in advance that one player goes first and the others follow, then it is *not* the same from everyone's point of view.

Comment: If players can not burn money, you are right there is a mistake somewhere. The sum of expected payoffs should be zero.

Comment: Negative means more losses than wins?  That's sensible.  But each individual win should be **worth** more than each individual loss.  I suspect you aren't weighting the wins and losses correctly.  For example: in a $N$ player game, the winner should gain $N-1$ times the loss of each of the other $N-1$ players (what goes into the kitty must come out).

Comment: Thanks, so I must have did the math wrong somewhere then...hmm...I'll have to figure it out.

Comment: Sergio - what do you mean by burn money by the way?

Comment: So basically the game is a modified version of Cee Lo.   Still not sure where my math is wrong though even in a 3 person game

Answer (score 0):

If the house doesn't take a cut, and if all players are identical, then the expected return is 0.

If all players are identical and rules do not favor anyone, then the probability of winning is

$p = 1/N$

where N is the number of players. The total pool is

$M = c N$

where c is the cost of the buy-in.

Then your expectation value is

$E = M p - c = 0$

**Edit:** More generally, if you have N players and i'th player has a chance of winning the pool that is $p_i$ then

$\sum_i (M p_i - c) = 0$

and

$\sum_i p_i = 1$

if $p_i = p$ then this reduces to my original statement.

Comment: Yes house doesn't take a cut and everyone has equal probabilities.

Comment: Then it is the simplest case and E=0 for everyone independent of N. After all, if everyone is as likely to win, then no matter what is the process, winning probability is by definition p=1/N and so you have $E=(1/N)\cdot(c\cdot N)-c = c-c = 0;$

Comment: This makes sense, so I guess now it's time to figure out where my math went wrong.